# How to change only the state of one button without affecting others when mapping the database in react Typescript?

Tags: typescript, database, button, mapping, react-typescript

I have created Enable/Disable buttons changed colors based on the Boolean value. All default buttons turn into Disable buttons and when clicked, all the buttons turn into the Enable buttons. How can I fix the problem.

```
function createData(
    id: number,
    name: string,
    enableStatus: boolean,
  ) {
    return { id, name, owner, category, join, status, enableStatus };
  }

const rows = [
    createData(1, 'quiz1', true),
    createData(2, 'quiz2', false),
    createData(3, 'quiz3', true),
    createData(4, 'quiz4', false),
    createData(5, 'quiz5', true),
  ];
const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)
function Surveys() {const handleButton = () => {
    setStatus(status => !status)
}
    return (
    {rows.map((row) => (
      <Button  variant="contained" color={status? 
               'warning': 'error'} onClick={updateAbsent} size="small">
               {status? "Enabled": 'Disabled'}
      </Button>
    )
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons are sharing one `useState`, so when you change that it affects all of them.

So instead, make that state store the status of all buttons. You can do that with an object type like this:

```
{ [id: number]: boolean | undefined }
```

This type is an object that can be indexed `number`s and each property is either missing (`undefined`) or set to a `boolean` value.

This lets you store the `status` of the row by the specific `id` of each row.

Now use that as your state:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState<{ [id: number]: boolean | undefined }>({})
```

Now to handle a click, create a function that accepts the id you want to toggle, and then toggle that id in state.

```
  const handleButton = (id: number) => {
    setStatus((status) => ({
      ...status,
      [id]: !status[id]
    }))
  }
```

And then in the `onClick` for each row, just pass in the `id` of that row:

```
  return rows.map((row) => (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color={status[row.id] ? 'warning' : 'error'} // check row.id status here
      onClick={() => handleButton(row.id)} // pass row.id here
      size="small"
    >
      {status ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}
    </Button>
  ))
```

Now when they click a button, new state is set where only the id of the row that was clicked is toggled.

And to check the status you need only to check `status[row.id]`.

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXA9L3ACyENAGs4KOAAMAQvhgwIAOylw0TSEqRKYXACZI0AGxTt6+JRmDK4chcoAUYRmEIAuCUoCeASg8ApEgANADoAUSMkEG1dLjoLKxs0dgokABEKFAdgPQ8lfBAAIyQobCUUaI9CGChgJQBzbG0UQsiyCiIPQogISJQlH1wuODh2GHwoJVw4HLKKpGwIAHctUrVU+ugvbAArCDrsao7CJvLW0nJxwhouah51JWrR5euAXjgAbWG1FMoM8gcAEZsCwAI74YAAL0BLGwNXwSB8mG+yVQf0yDgATCDwVDMbD6CgjMQkSjfukMQBmHEQyGUgnwxHIkao1L-LIAFhpUI5BLoRJJzJ+aIpAIArNzIWKGVAEaSALr3ZRPD5HK6HJAwdpXeVwd5EC6pAA8eA+OTyBWKUHlXR6fSmAB8CEoDHQ6kg9DQAHwOHDUHw8eKWGDWKYkCYANyQXkIDkGOBRyvgAAt+npInZFFN3tlcnB8kUSoNXl6hiMRsQtZciA4HGqiMXS77vuW4CF2-WTi3y2a9Da4ABCTu9xWt-0BkZ3EbfMYTKaMJaEEIgFBgWsLxtwBzdo2Z5TdkYR0zAfowV4AIge5HdenPB7UvWgrxww4XIRyuoA-KwlqYlHV6hYOAPBYEpGCgFhaH4NRk0McQYFgmZPVg9h72UABhIxgDEZ84z1UtUxdDN5CzBw3xyHwoIEMAUEIa5yOQkokHvQgoSQC9CBXIwjDvVsvXvF9q2ub8WDCM5Ij0ICQLSYBCBaCTIJ3Xg9yUfiRh8AM7iAA)

---

> I want to set the Status True/False based on variable enableStatus: boolean to set the default status.

You can pass a function to `useState` which will execute to derive the default value. Then in that function, just compute your initial state object:

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState<{ [id: number]: boolean | undefined }>(() => {
  const defaultStatus: { [id: number]: boolean | undefined } = {}
  for (const row of rows) {
    defaultStatus[row.id] = row.enableStatus
  }
  return defaultStatus
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that do the trick. However, I want to set the Status True/False based on variable `enableStatus: boolean`  to set the default status. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Just pass a function to `useState`. See my updated answer.